# Show node summary (teaser) as tooltip/ Alt/ Title text on hover over nodes titles on front page with Views

Tags: views, theming, 9, tooltips

I have a custom front page view showing nodes titles only without teasers. I want to have the teaser of each node show when hovering over any title. Something like:

```
<a href="{{ url }}" title="{{ node__teaser }}"> Node Title </a>
```

I am thinking I could edit the view to display teasers and I can then control their visibility on hover with css but I am curious to learn any idea to do it otherwise by including the node teaser in the title attribute instead if at all possible via Views or theme's twigs.

---

I'm going to answer my own question but first I'd love to learn from those who down-voted my question their reasons except for again discouraging a newbie here who's done all efforts to research and wrote a clear question. I only ask after I've exhausted all my search and it annoys me and discourage me when my question is unfairly down-voted and it seems this is an exclusive Drupal Answers trend !!!

Comment: The `title` attribute only accepts text, not HTML. So `title="{{ node__teaser }}"` ain't gonna render the HTML. What you're looking for is called "tooltip". You'll need to use some JS library, ex: [https://www.tippedjs.com/](https://www.tippedjs.com/)

Comment: You can use {{ node__teaser| striptags }} to get the text only of the summary.

Comment: @NoSssweat Thank you. I overcame this in twig by using the " |striptags" option as suggested by Hodba Khalaf  but still couldn't figure out  a way to do it to meet my question so I ended up solving it nicely in Views as shown in my own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of digging and trial and errors playing with twig and then Views I made it work exactly as I wanted in my Homepage view as follows:

The view has the following four Content fields in the same order below:

`Content:Body [Hidden]`  (**Formatter**: Summary or Trimmed)

`Content: Link to Content [hidden]` ("**Output the URL as text**" is checked)

`Content: Title` as follows:

**Link to the Content** is unchecked,

**Formatter**: *Plain text*

**Rewrite Rules**:  *Output this field as a custom link* selected.

**Link path:** {{ view_node }}

**Title text:** {{ body }}

Now whenever one hovers over a node link on front page they get a tooltip with the node summary. The link also links correctly and all as expected.

Please see the attached screenshot for more details.

[image]

`Content: Authored on (Authored on)` .....